# HQL java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql, h2

Hello can you please help me. I have been trying to fix this for past few days without any success. I am trying to query "Biljeska" objects and return them as Biljeska list. Classes setup:

Biljeznica.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "biljeznica")
public class Biljeznica implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5589212916227508153L;

    @Id
    @Column(name= "naziv")
    private String naziv;

    @Column(name= "opis")
    private String opis;

    public Biljeznica(){}
// getters and setters
```

Korisnik.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Korisnik extends NovaBiljeskaForm implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3476436475286629836L;

    @Id
    @Column(name= "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name= "ime")
    private String ime;

    @Column(name= "prezime")
    private String prezime;

    @Column(name= "username")
    private String nick;

    public Korisnik(){}
//getters and setters
```

Biljeska.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "biljeska")
public class Biljeska implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3706596321179671012L;

    @Id
    @Column(name= "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    @Column(name = "naslov")
    private String naslov;

    @Column(name = "tekst")
    private String tekst;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name ="korisnik")
    private Korisnik korisnik;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "biljeznica")
    private Biljeznica biljeznica;

    public Biljeska(){}
```

h2 schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id INT(11) IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ime VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
prezime VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(45),
password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
enabled TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
CREATE TABLE biljeznica (
naziv VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
opis VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE biljeska (
id INT(11) IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
naslov VARCHAR(100),
tekst VARCHAR(1000),
korisnik VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
biljeznica VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (korisnik) REFERENCES user (username),
FOREIGN KEY (biljeznica) REFERENCES biljeznica (naziv)
);
```

Data i am inserting into schema via test-data.sql :

```
INSERT INTO user(ime, prezime,username,password,enabled)
VALUES ('Ivo','Ivić','iivic','$2a$10$VQoRdaQK0KzAl4QoBzfZleRBcHitGS5jRA771ilGdL2DvkVTLDqSe', true);
INSERT INTO user(ime, prezime,username,password,enabled)
VALUES ('Marko','Markić','mmarkic','$2a$10$VQoRdaQK0KzAl4QoBzfZleRBcHitGS5jRA771ilGdL2DvkVTLDqSe', true);
INSERT INTO user(ime, prezime,username,password,enabled)
VALUES ('Pero','Perić','pperic','$2a$10$VQoRdaQK0KzAl4QoBzfZleRBcHitGS5jRA771ilGdL2DvkVTLDqSe', true);
INSERT INTO user(ime, prezime,username,password,enabled)
VALUES ('Adminko','Adminić','admin','$2a$10$VQoRdaQK0KzAl4QoBzfZleRBcHitGS5jRA771ilGdL2DvkVTLDqSe', true);
INSERT INTO user_role (username, role)
VALUES ('iivic', 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO user_role (username, role)
VALUES ('mmarkic', 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO user_role (username, role)
VALUES ('pperic', 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO user_role (username, role)
VALUES ('admin', 'ROLE_USER');
INSERT INTO user_role (username, role)
VALUES ('admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN');
INSERT INTO biljeznica(naziv, opis)
VALUES('Web aplikacije u Javi', 'Bilješke s predavanja iz kolegija web aplikacije u
Javi');
INSERT INTO biljeznica(naziv, opis)
VALUES('Razvoj aplikacija na Android platformi', 'Bilješke s predavanja kolegija razvoj
aplikacija na Android platformi');
INSERT INTO biljeznica(naziv, opis)
VALUES('Napredne teme računalnih mreža', 'Bilješke s predavanja napredne teme
računalnih mreža');
INSERT INTO biljeska(naslov, tekst, korisnik, biljeznica)
VALUES('Testni naslov', 'Testni tekst', 'iivic', 'Web aplikacije u Javi');
INSERT INTO biljeska(naslov, tekst, korisnik, biljeznica)
VALUES('Moj naslov', 'Moj tekst', 'pperic', 'Web aplikacije u Javi');
```

Method in repository class where i want to return list of Biljeska objects:

```
@Autowired
    public HibernateBiljeskaRepository(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
    public List<Biljeska> findAll() {
        return currentSession().createQuery("select b from Biljeska b, Biljeznica bi, Korisnik k where b.korisnik = k and b.biljeznica = bi",Biljeska.class).getResultList();
    }
```

Exception occurs at return statment of findAll() method

Error messagge i am getting:

```
Apr 28, 2017 1:19:01 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 22018, SQLState: 22018
Apr 28, 2017 1:19:01 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Data conversion error converting "iivic"; SQL statement:
select biljeska0_.id as id1_0_, biljeska0_.biljeznica as biljezni4_0_, biljeska0_.korisnik as korisnik5_0_, biljeska0_.naslov as naslov2_0_, biljeska0_.tekst as tekst3_0_ from biljeska biljeska0_ cross join biljeznica biljeznica1_ cross join user korisnik2_ where biljeska0_.korisnik=korisnik2_.id and biljeska0_.biljeznica=biljeznica1_.naziv [22018-193]
Apr 28, 2017 1:19:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/labos1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "iivic"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:922)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVPrimaryIndex.getKey(MVPrimaryIndex.java:338)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVDelegateIndex.find(MVDelegateIndex.java:69)
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.find(BaseIndex.java:128)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:169)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:467)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:537)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:542)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:655)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:341)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:309)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:36)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:110)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1481)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1441)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    at hr.tvz.hibernate.HibernateBiljeskaRepository.findAll(HibernateBiljeskaRepository.java:58)
    at hr.tvz.hibernate.HibernateBiljeskaRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d420114f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at hr.tvz.hibernate.HibernateBiljeskaRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7521f20.findAll(<generated>)
    at hr.tvz.controleri.NovaBiljeskaController.showSpremljeneBiljeske(NovaBiljeskaController.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am really confused and i do not understand why am i getting this error...
Thank you in advance!

Edit :

Solved thanks to Alex

Solution: change Biljeska attributes into

```
@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name ="korisnik", referencedColumnName="username")
private Korisnik korisnik;

@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "biljeznica", referencedColumnName="naziv")
private Biljeznica biljeznica;
```

and hql to :

```
"select b from Biljeska b"
```

Comment: suppose you can share the User.java where the exception happens.

Comment: Exception happens at line  return currentSession().createQuery("select b from Biljeska b, Biljeznica bi, Korisnik k where b.korisnik = k and b.biljeznica = bi",Biljeska.class).getResultList(); and user.java does not exist

Comment: suppose you follow this [post](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/bidirectional-onetomany-manytoone-association.html) on `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` relationships. your pojo  class is missing relationship.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL code you made `biljeska.korisnik` a foreign key to `user.username`. But in the Java code, you didn't specify what column of the `Korisnik` class the foreign key refers to, so it's trying to refer to the primary key, which is an integer and that's why you got `NumberFormatException`.

You must use `JoinColumn.referencedColumnName` in `Biljeska.korisnik` to reference the `username` column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me :) . + I just had to change hql query to "select b from Biljeska b". You got beer on me !!